# Getting a value sent by SignalR with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, signalr, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm trying to write a very simple message on the screen that when [signalr](/questions/tagged/signalr) send a value this message gets updated.

I have a very simple Hub:

```
public class Chat : Hub
{
    public Task Send(string message)
    {
        return Clients.All.InvokeAsync("Send", message);
    }
}
```

On the front-end I have the following [html](/questions/tagged/html):

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <p ng-bind="value"></p>
</div>
```

And the script is:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.value = "My Test Value";
});

chatConnection.on('Send', (message) => {
    app.scope.value = message;
});
```

What I am failing to understand is how do I access that value parameter so that I may update it.

EDIT:

The SignalR part works, the message comes through. The problem is that I am not sure how to update the value that is inside of that controller.  `app.scope.value = message;`

Comment: Did you start the connection? Do you see any traces in the console? Do you see the client sending requests to the server (Network tab in Developer tools)

Comment: @Pawel I updated my question

Comment: You are looking at this backwards.  SignalR can't update the angular property;  You'll have to have angular "subscribe" to the SignalR proxy, and then update the property in response to the proxy events.

Comment: @Claies could you write a short example and post as answer?

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/build-real-time-signalr-dashboard-angularjs/

Comment: @Claies yeah I've read that before, they got so much stuff going on its very difficult to follow, I was trying to dumb it down above to a very simple example so I can understand how all this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use observer pattern. Basically create a service which should do the following things:

1. Creates hub connection (handles start, reconnection, ....)
2. Support for example the following methods:

   - register for event (adds the caller to a list which contains
     interested members.)
   - unregister for event (removes the caller from the list with the interesed members.)
3. In the case a new message from server inform all observers

**Example:**

(Pseudocode extracted from my solution (to big to show all)):

Server (here called hubWrapperService):

```
    var yourHubProxy = $.connection.yourHub;        
        yourHubProxy.client.yourMethodWhichServerCanCall= function (params){      
           // Inform observers. Iterate to over all your observers and inform them                     
           notifyObservers(params);
        };

    // Start connection.
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {            
        ...
        });

    }).fail(function (error) {...

    });

   function registerToEvent(callback) {
                $log.debug("ServiceHub:  getConnectionEvent called");
                // Add caller to you observer list. (here serviceInitObservers)
            }

   function notifyServiceInitObservers() {
                angular.forEach(serviceInitObservers, function (callback) {
                    callback.callback();
                });
        }
```

In your Controller (inject service and register for events):

```
hubWrapperServer.registerToEvent(function () {
        serviceHub.getAllDevices().then(function (params) {    // Do something in your controller
        });
      });
```

There is also a wrapper service available
https://github.com/JustMaier/angular-signalr-hub

Answer (score 0):

```
poker.client.showAllCards = function (show) {  
    $scope.allCardsShowing = show;
    $scope.$apply();
};
```

`$scope.$apply()`, refresh the Angularjs context, and this working for me.

I get this form article: [Consensus: SignalR + AngularJS](http://nickberardi.com/signalr-and-angularjs/)